# save button does not save in .txt file Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    Dim strLineFromSave As String
              'This method below returns a String of 81 characters long.'
    strLineFromSave = grid.udsSave()
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt*"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
            'For loop to write a line every 9 characters, so you get a 9x9 grid.'
        For intCounter As Integer = 0 To (strLineFromSave.Length - 1) Step 9
            Dim strTemp = strLineFromSave.Substring(intCounter, 9)
            sw.WriteLine(strTemp)
        Next
        sw.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above is made to save my Sudoku game into a .txt file.

Problem I have is that whenever I click the save button, everything works, up until the point that it didn't save the file as a .txt file. It just saved it as a 'file'.

Does anybody understand where this comes from? And how do I fix this?

***NOTE:*** **I have tried setting the SaveFileDialog1.filter to txt files only, this did not help.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter does not have any effect on the type of file being saved, just those that appear in the dialog (similar to opening). The actual extension ".txt" needs to be saved with the file when you first create it. This is how windows knows that the file is a text file. Otherwise if you just save it as "MySudoku" it will not include a file extension.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.defaultext(v=vs.110).aspx

Try using the defaultext property.

```
SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This Worked! Will mark as an answer as soon as this page will let me :D